# Get input[text] value before special characters are trimmed in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have a from. User can fill an input field with text that contains special characters like \n, \t and etc. I have to replace these special characters and add it back as value of the input field.
for example:

- user input is: hello, \n how are you doing? \t this is a sample text.
- This is what I need: hello, newline how are you doing? tab this is a sample text.

I am using JQuery and Typescript 2.4

Comment: So, what's the problem exactly? What have you stuck at?

Comment: So far I have tried keyup and paste events and I get the already trimmed values.
ie: if I copy "hello, \n how are you doing? \t this is a sample text." as input I get "hello," as (document.getElementById('testingInput') as HTMLInputElement).value;

Comment: Please paste the code you tried.?

Comment: I found the problem.
Since I used text editor not Textarea it removed the text after /n.
I used textarea instead and it worked.
thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```js
$('#input').keyup(function () {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var replaceWithBr = val.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>');
  var replaceWithTab = replaceWithBr.replace(/\\t/g, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
  $('#result').html(replaceWithTab);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<div id="result"></div>
```